# Why is the child component not updating with state of parent?

Tags: reactjs

I am passing my parent state to my child component, but when I print props in the child component I get the previous state of the parent component instead of the most up to date state. I'm pretty sure it's because `this.setState` is asynchronous.

```
  handleClick(event) {
   const value = event.currentTarget.value;
   this.setState({ touched: value });
  }

 render() {
  return(
   <ChildComponent {...this.state} />
  )

 }
```

Comment: But I have to render ChildComponent regardless of state, if I put a callback how would I make sure the already rendered ChildComponent receives the updated state.

Comment: React does that automatically. When the state changes, the component is re-rendered and the new props are passed to the child(ren).

Comment: Then how come when I console.log() my props in the child components it prints the previous state

Comment: Where do you log it? In render()?

Comment: in my child component code not above. It's in the `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps is before the component updates. this.props is the previous props. what you need is either `componentDidUpdate` or look at the next props coming in

Comment: Try `componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) { console.log(newProps); }`.

Comment: Yup that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`componentWillReceiveProps` is before component update render. [**If you read the docs**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) they explain you have a reference to the next props coming in.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState){
    this.props.something // old value
    nextProps.something // new value
}
```

now did update happens after the render finishes.

```
componentDidUpdate(previousProps){
    this.props.somehting // new value
    previousProps.something // old value
}
```

your issue is you are printing out the old props before the new ones have a change to update the old ones.  what you need is either `componentDidUpdate` or look at the next props coming in